# Struts 2 Xml validation: One set of validation on multiple fields

Tags: struts2, struts, struts-validation

I have lots of number field let say num1, num2 ...
Now I am looking for way I can apply a set of validation on all field rather than writing same validations multiple times.

Here is set of two validation for requiredString and Number check

```
<validators>
        <field name="num1">
            <field-validator type="requiredstring">
                <message>Field cannot be left blank</message>
            </field-validator>

            <field-validator type="regex" short-circuit="true">
                <param name="expression"><![CDATA[^[0-9]+$]]></param>
                     <message>Not a valid Number</message>
             </field-validator>
        </field>

</validators>
```

Tia

Comment: Validations are per-field. Why use a string for a number field, though?

Comment: If I remove requiredstring then it will not be handled by number check only. main problem is can I use a single validation code for multiple fields.

Comment: As I said, validations are per-field. You could always write a custom validator.